# VS2013: Add Service Reference misses a contract

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, visual-studio-2013, service-reference

I am trying to add a Service Reference to a class library in a VS2013 solution. When I point the Add Service Reference dialog at the mex endpoint of the service, I see the following 3 contracts:

[image: Add Service Reference dialog]

I want to make use of the service that implements IPAWebService but I cannot figure out what to add to the URL I enter in the dialog to point the new Service Reference to just this service. Instead, VS2013 is generating a proxy just for the IClientAccessPolicy and nothing else. What am I doing wrong?

As an aside, I have added a reference to the same service in another project and get *all* contracts implemented. Also, if I point the WCF Test Client at the URL I'm trying in the Add Service Reference dialog, I can see and consume all services. Finally, svcutil also generates a full set of proxies for all services.

Comment: I see that your service is specified as /mex. What happens when you set the service url (without the metadata exchange path)

Comment: @mrtig exactly the same unfortunately.

Comment: Interestingly, if I change the Framework version the project targets to Framework 4, the IPAWebService and IPAGetServices proxies and their associated classes appear in the Object Browser. As soon as I upgrade to Framework 4.5 again, they disappear. This is without doing a rebuild, or an update of the service reference. Also, if I add a Framework 2.0 Web Reference to the WSDL instead of MEX, all the proxies I expect appear.